# Help with a pigeonhole principle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer. Use the Pigeonhole Principle to prove that in any set
of $n + 1$ integers from $\{1, 2, . . . , 2n\}$, there are two integers that are consecutive (i.e., differ by one).

Comment: First assume that your picked integers are $j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_{n+1}$, and then try to insert in between consecutive ones other integers. How many do you get?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Each set $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, ..., \{2n - 1, 2n\}$ contains zero, one, or two elements of the set. If one of the sets contains two integers in our given set, we're done; if not, bad things happen.

Comment: Since the set of $n+1$ integers from $\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$ , will contain more than $n$ integers then we can say that they are atleast two integers in the set would differ by one. Am I right?